# build2 set output directory

Tags: c++, build2

I am new to `build2` and following along thair [toolchain introduction](https://build2.org/build2-toolchain/doc/build2-toolchain-intro.xhtml).

I currently have the following structure:

```
demo/
- build/
  - bootstrap.build
  - root.build
- demo/
  - main.cpp
  - buildfile
- buildfile
- ...
```

./build/bootstrap.build:

```
project = demo

using version
using config
using test
using install
using dist
```

./build/root.build:

```
cxx.std = 20

using cxx

hxx{*}: extension = hpp
cxx{*}: extension = cpp
```

./buildfile:

```
./: {*/ -build/}
```

./demo/buildfile:

```
exe{demo}: {hxx cxx}{*}
```

When I run `b` everything works but all the binry and metadata file get put into `./demo`.

But when I run `b demo/@demo-out/` I get the following error:

```
error: out_base suffix does not match src_root
  info: src_root: .\
  info: out_base: out\
```

As I am new to `build2` I dont quite get what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

I *just* ran into the exact same situation, and discovered that the system is expecting you to invoke the command from the directory *above* the project. (Which, in hindsight, makes sense since it's describing an out-of-tree build.) See this example:

```
❯ bdep new -l c++ -t exe demo
created new executable project demo in /Users/xxx/projects/demo/

> cd demo

> b
c++ demo/cxx{demo}
ld demo/exe{demo}

> b demo/@demo-out/
error: out_base suffix does not match src_root
  info: src_root: ./
  info: out_base: demo-out/

> cd ..

> b demo/@demo-out/
mkdir fsdir{demo-out/}
mkdir demo-out/fsdir{demo/}
c++ demo/demo/cxx{demo}@demo-out/demo/
ld demo-out/demo/exe{demo}
```